# Proving that $\hat{x} = x$ in least square

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing, least-squares

I am trying to show that if $Ax=b$ has a unique solution $x$, then the least square solution $\hat{x}$ is the exact one (i.e., $\hat{x} = x$).

**My attempt:**
We know that for $A x = b$ to have an exact unique solution, then $A$ is a full column rank and $b$ is in the column space of $A$.

To minimize the error in the least square, the error $e$ of the projection of $b$ into $C(A)$ has to be orthogonal to the column space of $A$:

$$
e \perp C(A) \Longrightarrow e \in N(A^\top)\\
\Longrightarrow A^\top e = 0\\
A^\top (b-A\hat{x}) = 0
$$

Here I get stuck, because $A^\top e = 0$ might have a special solution (i.e., we don't know if the columns of $A^\top$ are linearly independent).

How can I show that $A^\top e = 0$ has no special solution? (i.e., $e$ must be the zeros vector)? and therefore, $\hat{x}$ is exact? or is there a better way to prove this?

Comment: the least square solution minimizes the distance from $Ax$ to $b$. If there is a true solution, then it will do so. So we are done. I don't get your question.

Comment: Showing this more formally (as a proof).

Comment: how are you defining the least-squares solutions? if you are defining it as the vector closest in a least-squares sense, there really is nothing to prove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $Ax=b$ has a unique solution, $\text{nullity}(A)=0$ and therefore $\text{nullity}(A^{T}A)=0$

$\hspace{.3 in}$since $A$ and $A^{T}A$ have the same nullspace.

Since $Ax=b\implies A^{T}Ax=A^{T}b$, and since $A^{T}A\hat{x}=A^{T}b$, $\;\;A^{T}A(x-\hat{x})=0\implies x-\hat{x}=0$

Comment: How does the nullity of $A$ and $A^T$ help? Couldn't you start the proof from the last line? (i.e., starting from "Since $Ax=b\implies A^{T}Ax=A^{T}b ...$)?

Comment: @hayer Since $A^{T}A(x-\hat{x})=0$, $x-\hat{x}$ is in the nullspace of $A^{T}A$; and this nullspace is just the zero vector since $\text{nullity}(A^{T}A)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Id $Ax=b$ has an unique solution then $A$ has number of rows not less than number of columns and it has the full column rank.  When number of rows more than number of columns then a non zero $e$ will exist such that $A^Te=0$ but this vector cannot come from $b-Ax$ for any x. Becauseby assumption $b=Ax^*$ and then $A^Te=A^TA(x^*-x)$ can be zero iff $x^*=x$